# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've inherited some swift code which performs a refreshObject immediately after fetching from core data.  The objects being fetched have a relationship to another table.  The fetch and refreshObject are inside a performBlockAndWait.  The code is below.  The crash appeared to begin in iOS9.

- Any idea why the refreshObject is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  What is the fix?
- What is the purpose of doing a refreshObject immediately after the fetch?  This table contains just a few rows.  Is this necessary?  Any downside to removing all together?

  ```
  context.performBlockAndWait {
      let className = self.className()
      let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: className)
      groups = (try? context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as? [FavoriteLocationGroup]
      if groups != nil {
          groups!.sortInPlace { $0.name < $1.name }
          for group in groups! {
              context.refreshObject(group, mergeChanges: false) <<< crashes here
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

[image: value of context]

[image: what group is]

Comment: this is swift not objc ;) fixed question and tags

Comment: what is the value of context when you call refresh

Comment: and what is group. and do you have a notification observer that reacts to the merge?

Comment: *"What is the purpose of doing a refreshObject immediately after the fetch?"* None that I can think of. I'd want to ask the person who wrote it, if possible, or consult the git history, if available.

Comment: It turns the objects into faults, but it's kinda pointless to sort and fault outside the fetch and inside a block where the result is probably being passed across thread boundaries...

Comment: Hi Daij-Djan, Thanks for fixing the tags.  The value of context when I call refresh is shown in the attached jpeg.  I also added a screen grab of the data model which shows what group is (a record in FavoriteLocationGroup).  There is an observer, but it only gets called when something is added or deleted from core data.  It doesn't react to the refreshObject call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you try replacing sortInPlace line with

```
groups = groups!.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

I've hit similar issue. The app was crashing in Release mode in random place after calling sortInPlace. It seems that it causes some kind of memory corruption. sort() works well.

Upd: I was able to reproduce the crash with the following code (also crashes in OS X Cocoa apps):

```
import Cocoa

class MyObject {
    var x: Int?
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    var array = [MyObject]()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        for x in 0..<100000 {
            let object = MyObject()
            object.x = x
            array.append(object)
        }
        array.sortInPlace { $0.x < $1.x } // CRASH
    }
    ...
}
```